# Is it possible to logout from an app or website on offline mode?

Tags: validation, testing

Just wanna gauge your thought on this issue. Recently, I tested an app
and when I logged out in offline mode (i.e. no Internet connection),
the app is, to my amazement, ABLE to log out. Furthermore, the client said it was an expected behavior!
I'm a bit bemused because usually when we log out from an app/website by disabling the Internet connection, it should throw out an exception like "There is no Internet connection", right? Surely there must be a validation token in place.

Many thanks indeed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
This is an open-ended question. Please add an example or something someone can help with. Most offline modes save/store data something like a localdb and sync up later. The online session will logout after a period of time typically.

Comment: Ya, thought of attaching logcat but it's way too long. Nevermind. Thanks anyway.